# Unable to get FolderPath from RDOFolder

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am trying to get the RDOFolder Path, It is possible in Interop.Outlook by coding MAPIFolder.FolderPath

string path = rdoFolder.FolderPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both classes provide the `FolderPath` property:

- [MAPIFolder.FolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.folderpath?view=outlook-pia)
- [RDOFolder.FolderPath](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm)

It is up to you which one is to choose.

Answer (score 0):

`FolderPath` property is implemented by the `IRDOFolder2` interface (derived from `RDOFolder`).
Try to cast `rdoFolder` variable to `IRDOFolder2`